# I need help for bubble sort in c

Tags: c, bubble-sort

How can I display the input user of this code. I am using bubble sort but I cannot display the input.

Here's my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void) {
    int array[100];

    int count;

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
        if(array[i] == 0) break;
    }

    int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        int swapped = 0;
        for(int ctr = 0; ctr < size - i - 1; ++ctr) {
            if(array[ctr] > array[ctr + 1]) {
                int temp = array[ctr];
                array[ctr] = array[ctr + 1];
                array[ctr + 1] = temp;

                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
        if(swapped == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if(i == size - 1) {
            printf("%d", array[i]);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d, ", array[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("]");
        
    return 0;
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
Enter·number·1:·1
Enter·number·2:·2
Enter·number·3:·3
Enter·number·4:·4
Enter·number·5:·5
Enter·number·6:·0
[1,·2,·3,·4,·5]
```

I cannot display the 1 2 3 4 5.... How can I display?

Comment: It's really not at all clear what it is you want to display. Are you looking for the number of numbers input? Or something else? But the `int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);` line will return a fixed `size` value, not dependent on usse rinput.

Comment: The array always has 100 elements, no matter how many you enetered! ... but you are counting the number of elements as you enter them, just use that number throughout the rest of your code.

Comment: `int size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);` -> `int size = i;`. But there are possibly more issues, I didn't check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation of the size doesn't work like you did it. **sizeof(array)** will give you the total amount of of bytes of the array (of all 100 spaces). So your size will allway be 100.

Instead of calculating the size it's easyer to count the inputs like this:

```
int size=0;

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    if(array[i] == 0) break;
    size++;
}
```

Comment: When you put code inline like this, you can surround it with single backticks instead of triple for inline code, `like this`.

Answer (score 0):

The user can enter `i` values in the array due to the break statement within the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("Enter number %d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    if(array[i] == 0) break;
}
```

So you need to keep this value and use it the following for loops because it can differ from the value of the expression  `sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])`